# How to store data from Pubnub history and make it available to all controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pubnub

I'm trying to get a history data from `Pubnub.history()`, store that data and update the views by using different controllers.

I've tried creating a service:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app')
          .service('pubnubService', ['Pubnub',
          pubnubService
  ]);

  function pubnubService(Pubnub){
    var history;
    Pubnub.history({
        channel  : 'ParkFriend',
        limit    : 1,
        callback : function(historyData) {
          console.log("callback called");
          history = historyData;
        }
    });

    return {
      getHistory : function() {
        console.log("return from getHistory called");
          return history;
      }
    };
  }

})();
```

The problem is, `getHistory()` returns the data before `Pubnub.history()`. I need to make sure that history data is stored on `history` before returning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Pubnub.history` is async, your `getHistory` function have to be an async function too.

Try the following:

```
function pubnubService(Pubnub) {

    return {
        getHistory: function(cb) { // cb is a callback function

            Pubnub.history({
                channel: 'ParkFriend',
                limit: 1,
                callback: function(historyData) {
                    console.log("callback called");
                    cb(historyData);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

To use this service, you can't use it as a synchronous function (*i.e.*, like `var history = Pubnub.getHistory()`), you need to pass a function as parameter to act like a callback.

Correct usage:

```
Pubnub.getHistory(function(history) { // here you have defined an anonym func as callback

    console.log(history);
});
```